# External ultrafilters definitions

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic, ultrafilters

I am reading a paper by Goldberg, in which he defines ultrafilter over a model of set theory (not transitive). These are the definitions:
[image]

I get the definition of an M-ultrafilter, it is a real subset of the boolean algebra $P^M(X)$ in which union and intersection are obviously defined in $M$.
What I don't get is the other definitions: in $\gamma$-completeness over $M$, why is it correct to look at $(\cap F)^M$ and ask if it is in $U$? I mean if $F$ is a real subset of $U$, that doesn't mean that all it's $M$-elements (the sets $M$ thinks that are elements of $F$) are in $U$.

Am I missing something? can someone elaborate on the definitions?
Thank you very much.

Comment: Where is the confusion? $F$ is a subset of $P^M(X)$ and $F$ is in $M$, so $M$ knows that $F$ consists of subsets of $X$. Hence $\bigcap F$ is a subset of $X$ in $M$, so we can ask if it is in U.

Comment: Does $M$ thinks that $F$ is a subset of $P^M(X)$? If yes than $M$ knows that $F$ consists of subsets of $X$.  But this isn't implied by the fact that $F$ is an actual subset of $P^M(X)$

Comment: Why not? Any counterexample?

Comment: $P^M(X)$ is the collection of sets in $M$ that $M$ thinks are subsets of $X$. I couldn't see any problem

Comment: I guess there is something very basic I don't understand. Is $P^M(X)$ a set in $M$? is $P^M(X)$ really the collection you mentioned, or just $M$ thinks that?

Comment: I was sort of sloppy here. It is true that the definition is not literally correct. I wanted to identify elements of $M$ with their extensions in $V$ when it is unambiguous. So $F\subseteq U$ really means that $\text{ext}(F)\subseteq U$, where $\text{ext}(F) = \{s : M\vDash s\in F\}$. Feel free to email me if you have other questions like this.

Answer (score 2):

When relativizing functions we need a formula defining the function (see the section on relativization in chapter IV of Kunen's *Set Theory*). For instance, $(\bigcap F)^M$ can be defined as the unique $x \in M$ such that
$$\forall z \in x \cap M \ \exists y \in F \cap M \ (z \in y) \, \wedge \, \forall w \in M \ [\forall z \in w \cap M \ \exists y \in F \cap M \ (z \in y) \, \rightarrow$$
$$\rightarrow \, \forall z \in w \cap M \ (z \in x).$$
This need not be the same as $\bigcap (F \cap M)$, because $M$ doesn't necessarily have witnesses for all elements of $\bigcap (F \cap M)$ being in $(\bigcap F)^M$.

The reason for asking that $(\bigcap F)^M$ be in $U$ is that $(\bigcap F)^M$ is the greatest lower bound of $F$ according to $M$.